# How to make TelegramBot work constantly, without manually starting my Java-program all the time?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I am novice and I have written the code of my TelegramBot in Eclipse. It works fine, but I would like to know how can i make it work constantly without me launching the **Java-application**. I guess I should use server for this. Thanks

**Edit**: Added the Java code

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class MyFirstBot  extends TelegramLongPollingBot{

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "TheBot Version0.01";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                    .setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
         if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().isCommand()){
             try{
                 switch(update.getMessage().getText()){ //reads command
                 case("/hello"):
                    message.setText("Hi there!"); 
                    sendMessage(message); //says hello
                    break;
                 case("/date"):
                    message.setText(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
                    sendMessage(message); //tells time and date
                    break;  
                 default:
                    message.setText("Invalid Value");
                    sendMessage(message);} //in case no such command exists
             }
             catch(TelegramApiException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }          
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "xxx";
    }

}
```

Comment: so show the code

Comment: @JacekCz done...

Comment: you should probably not include bot token, since anyone who has it, can control your bot

Comment: @Cargeh oh, completely forgot about it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a host that supports Java. you can also get a server, install java on it, and then compile and launch your program there. then your bot will always be available.

or if you don't want to spend money, you can export your project as a runnable Jar file. then put it in your system startup.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that i have some deposit on DigitalOcean. So i will try it

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend exporting your application into a .jar file and running it with task scheduler (Windows) or making a cronjob to run it (Linux). If you have an Amazon Web Services account you can also use a Lambda function. If needed you can buy a small computer like a raspberry pi and run it on there as if it were a "server".

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old computer that you don't use, you can simply run your bot on it.
It will be similar to Raspberry PI, but you don't need to spend money at all.
Moreover, it might be even more efficient.

Comment: Your old computer will probably use quite a bit more power than a Pi but sure, why not?